# refactoring callback inside model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, callback

I am pretty new to rails and I am trying to create a callback that will apply user information before a record is saved.

Here is the callback:

```
def add_resolution_name
  if self.res_desc_changed?
      self.res_provided_name = current_user.first_name
    elsif self.res_desc_changed? && self.res_approved?
      self.res_provided_name = current_user.first_name
      self.res_approved_name = current_user.first_name
    elsif self.res_approved_changed? && self.res_approved?
      self.res_approved_name = current_user.first_name
    elsif self.res_approved_changed? && !self.res_approved?
      self.res_approved_name = nil
  end
  save
  logger.info "pocessed resolution information... #{current_user.first_name}"
end
```

As you can see it's pretty ugly and I don't have access to the current_user inside the ticket model. Should I put this into a presenter or service? Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In rails, there's class called `ActiveRecord::Observer` which allows you to add some event listeners to your own model e.g. `before_save`, `after_save`. Have a look here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html

For example

```
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def before_save(comment)
    # your code for add resolution here
  end
end
```

Comment: From what I read the observer is no longer being supported in Rails 4. My app is currently Rails 4.0.0.rc2, is there any other option?

Comment: It's not really deprecated, I think they just extracted it to a gem  extension instead. Here's the link https://github.com/rails/rails-observers